# How to define a Linux kernel Kconfig item that must at least select one of its sub-options to make it work?

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

I am writing a kernel module that has two low-level options can be used. Both these 2 options can be select as M/Y/N, but at least one of them must be selected, else the module will not work. Just like below:

```
[*]   Enable FOO support                      
       <M>     Back-end A
       <M>     Back-end B
```

I write it as below, but both 2 sub-options can be unselected.

```
config FOO
   bool "Enable FOO support"
config BACKEND_A
   tristate "Back-end A"
   depends on FOO
   depends on SUBSYSTEM_X
config BACKEND_B
   tristate "Back-end B"
   depends on FOO
   depends on SUBSYSTEM_Y
```

How to write such config in kconfig?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both backends `A` and `B` cannot be loaded into the kernel *at the same time*, `choice` configuration entry seems to be the best there:

```
config FOO
    bool "Enable FOO support"

choice
    prompt "Select back-end for FOO"
    depends on FOO

    config BACKEND_A
         tristate "Back-end A"
         depends on SUBSYSTEM_X
    config BACKEND_B
         tristate "Back-end B"
         depends on SUBSYSTEM_Y
endchoice
```

Behaviour of `choice` is described in [Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt):

> While a boolean choice only allows a single config entry to be
> selected, a tristate choice also allows any number of config entries
> to be set to 'm'. This can be used if multiple drivers for a single
> hardware exists and only a single driver can be compiled/loaded into
> the kernel, but all drivers can be compiled as modules.

Example of usage `choice` with `tristate`: [linux/scripts/kconfig/tests/choice/Kconfig](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/48b1320a674e1ff5de2fad8606bee38f724594dc/scripts/kconfig/tests/choice/Kconfig).

Comment: Thanks, it  works. The only one little problem is user still can unselect all backends which result in a non-useable build. But anyway, it can prompt user to select it, then its user's buinness.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `FOO` non-editable and select it using reverse dependencies:

```
config FOO
        tristate

menu "FOO support"

config BACKEND_A
        tristate "Back-end A"
        depends on SUBSYSTEM_X
        select FOO
config BACKEND_B
        tristate "Back-end B"
        depends on SUBSYSTEM_Y
        select FOO

endmenu
```

Comment: Another good idea, maybe I can make FOO only shown when at least one backend is selected.